302 Moved Temporarily
We are trying to fetch the data using below URL:
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/MAUDE/ftparea/DEVICEAdd.zip
but it continuously gives below error as:
Reusing existing connection to www.accessdata.fda.gov:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Kindly help
Thanks,
Shailendra Jetpuria

The openFDA team does not manage that Web page; however, if you configure your code to include a User-Agent header with your requests, that will fix the issue:
bash-3.2$ wget -U "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)" https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/MAUDE/ftparea/deviceadd.zip
--2024-05-15 12:39:30--  https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/MAUDE/ftparea/deviceadd.zip
Resolving www.accessdata.fda.gov (www.accessdata.fda.gov)... 23.208.60.116
Connecting to www.accessdata.fda.gov (www.accessdata.fda.gov)|23.208.60.116|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7053998 (6.7M) [application/x-zip-compressed]
Saving to: ‘deviceadd.zip’

deviceadd.zip                                   100%[=====================================================================================================>]   6.73M  26.0MB/s    in 0.3s    

2024-05-15 12:39:30 (26.0 MB/s) - ‘deviceadd.zip’ saved [7053998/7053998]



Thank you Denis , it works
